# Input label on two lines next to input field

Tags: html, css, forms

I want to have one label that is associated with the input field.  Some of the labels need to go on more than one line.  However, I am not able to view the text. What I am trying to achieve is shown below:

Label 1                      `<input />`
sub text for label 1

The code I currently have is as follows:

`<div class="row">`
`<label for="height">Height (help text here)</label>`
`<input name="height" id="height" ... />`
`</div>`

CSS:

`form { width: 100%; overflow: hidden; margin-top: -20px;}`

`form .row { height: 100%; overflow: hidden; padding-left: 140px; width: 295px; line-height: 30px; position: relative; margin-bottom: 6px; }`

`form label { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; line-height: 32px; text-align: left; width: 110px; font-size: 14px; display: inline-block}`

There are a few rows that need to be formatted like this.  Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: There is a strong, justified sentiment to avoid using tables just for layout purposes.  However, when you mention having multiple rows, it makes me think that maybe this is one of those times when using  tables would make sense.

Comment: for me overridded float input in bootstrap as root of the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<div class="row">
  <label for="height">Height <br /><span>(help text here)</span></label>
  <input name="height" id="height" ... />
</div>


label {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
```

make the label a block element so you can put a br. not a good solution also but it works :P

Comment: Yes this worked!  I had to change a couple line-heights I had set as well.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
<div class="row">
<label for="height">Height (help text here)</label><input name="height" id="height" ... /><br/>
<label for="height">Sub text</label>
</div>
```

It may be a workaround to your issue, but not a perfect solution

Comment: When I try that both labels overlap each other, but are inline with the input field.

Comment: I edited my code, I forgot a `<br/>`. I get them right as you wanted **without** the CSS : the `position:absolute` makes them overlap indeed

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
<div class="row">
<label for="height">Height</label>
<input name="height" id="height" ... />
<label for="height" class="help">help text here</label>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.row label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40%;
}

.row input {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 0 0 5%;
}

.row label.help {
    display: block;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/H55mX/).

Comment: I tried this, but I saw the labels were overlapping.  It might have something to do with another style I had applied though.